# Insert into in order or open form to specific record while still able to view other records

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba

My command button runs SQL to write specific fields from a few tables into one table: tbl_logdata.  I then have a form that I use to view the records that have been inserted into the table.  When I open the form it always goes to a random record.  I have added a sequence field but I can't seem to find a way to open the form to start at that first record in the sequence.

Adding it to the where statement just filters the form to show only records with sequence number 1.

From my research I can't add an ORDER BY to my SQL.  I have added an autoID to tbl_logdata but the data isn't going into the table in sequence order so the autoID is just as random as the order the items are being added.

I have spent so long on this that I am seeing stars. I appreciate any suggestions.

```
Private Sub cmdPlantDown_Click()
Me.[txtDate] = Date
Me.txtTime = Time()
Me.txtLog = 4

DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tbl_logdata ( log_ID, Log_Date, Log_Time,       Staff_Initials, tag, unit, Sequence, Log_Route ) " & _
"SELECT [Forms]![frm_menu]![txtLog_ID] AS LogID, " & _
"[Forms]![frm_menu]![txtDate] AS Log_Date, [Forms]![frm_menu]![txtTime] AS     Log_Time, " & _
"[Forms]![frm_menu]![cboStaff] AS Staff_Initials,      tbl_plantdown_sequence.tag, tbl_tags.unit,tbl_plantdown_sequence.Sequence,     Format([Forms]![frm_menu]![txtLog],'#') AS Log_Route " & _
"FROM tbl_tags INNER JOIN tbl_plantdown_sequence ON tbl_tags.tag = tbl_plantdown_sequence.tag"

DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_data_input_plantdownlog", acNormal, , "Log_ID = '" & Me.txtLog_ID & "'", , acWindowNormal

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either add `ORDER BY Log_Date, Log_Time ASC` to you query or SQL you use as source for your form or, in form design view, specify the fields to sort on.

Comment: Yep. Sorting always happens when **viewing** data (SELECT), not when inserting data.

Comment: I have added the ORDER BY into the SQL and also to the Form Load event, I have also sorted the source table by the sequence field as you suggested @Gustav and it works most of the time, but occasionally it doesn't.    Is there any way to make sure it sorts correctly each time so that when the form opens it opens to the first record?

Comment: Yes, use as source for the form a query that sorts _desc_ on `Log_date, Log_time`